# useEffect running multiple times causing journal multiple entry creations and deletions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm facing an issue where the `useEffect` in my React component is running 8-9 times, resulting in the creation and deletion of multiple journal entries. I have tried using `useCallback` for each function within the `useEffect` as suggested in other posts, but it leads to an infinite loop. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Am I using the cleanup function properly?

###### Things I have tried that havent worked:

- Using use callback for the functions in the use effect
- Getting rid of the cleanup function to find the root cause
- Avoid updating states from local storage.
- `n` number of changes to the overall to `useEffect` function.

I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Here's the code for my component:

```
import Editor from '../components/text-editor/Editor';
import Layout from '../containers/Layout';
import { useUser } from '../contexts/UserContext';
import {
    getJournalEntryById,
    updateJournalEntry,
    createJournalEntry,
    deleteJournalEntry,
} from '../services/journalEntryService';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMenu } from '../contexts/NavDrawerContext';

// Get the journal ID from local storage

const Journal = () => {
    const { userID, toggleDarkMode } = useUser();
    const [initialContent, setInitialContent] = useState([]);
    const [selectedBlocks, setSelectedBlocks] = useState([]);
    const [isSelectionActive, setIsSelectionActive] = useState(false);
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
    const [isPromptDisplayVisible, setIsPromptDisplayVisible] = useState(false);
    const [currentMood, setCurrentMood] = useState('happy');
    const [isFocusModeOn, setIsFocusModeOn] = useState(false);
    const [journalID, setJournalID] = useState('');

    const [isTextEditorMenuCollapsed, setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed] =
        useState(false);
    const containerRef = useRef(null);

    // Function to scroll to the bottom of the editor
    const scrollToBottom = () => {
        if (containerRef.current) {
            containerRef.current.scrollTop = containerRef.current.scrollHeight;
        }
    };

    const updateJournalID = (id) => {
        setJournalID(id);
        localStorage.setItem('journalID', id);
    };

    const resetJournalID = () => {
        setJournalID('');
        localStorage.removeItem('journalID');
    };

    // number of times the useEffect hook is called
    let effectCountRef = useRef(0);



    useEffect(() => {
        const journalIDFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('journalID');
        if (journalIDFromLocalStorage) {
            setJournalID(journalIDFromLocalStorage);
        }
        console.log(`useEffect hook called ${effectCountRef.current} times`);
        effectCountRef.current++;

        const fetchAndUpdateJournalStates = async (id) => {
            try {
                if (id?.length) {
                    const journalEntry = await getJournalEntryById(id);

                    if (journalEntry) {
                        const { content, mood, _id } = journalEntry;
                        const blocks = JSON.parse(content);
                        setInitialContent(blocks);
                        setCurrentMood(mood);
                        updateJournalID(_id);
                    }
                } else {
                    const response = await createJournalEntry(
                        initialContent,
                        currentMood
                    );
                    updateJournalID(response._id);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(
                    'Error fetching or creating journal entry:',
                    error
                );
                resetJournalID();
            }
        };

        fetchAndUpdateJournalStates(journalID);

        return () => {
            const deleteJournalIfEmpty = async (id) => {
                try {
                    if (!id) return;

                    const response = await getJournalEntryById(id);

                    const content = JSON.parse(response.content);

                    if (content.length === 0) {
                        await deleteJournalEntry(id);
                        console.log('Journal entry deleted');
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(
                        'Error deleting journal entry if empty:',
                        error
                    );
                }
            };

            deleteJournalIfEmpty(journalID);
        };
    }, [journalID]);

    const handleJournalUpdate = useCallback(
        async (editor) => {
            // Update the content state and scroll to the bottom of the editor
            const newContent = editor.topLevelBlocks;
            captureSelectedBlocks(editor);
            scrollToBottom();

            if (newContent?.length && journalID?.length) {
                try {
                    await updateJournalEntry(journalID, 'content', newContent);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Failed to update journal entry:', error);
                }
            }
        },
        [journalID]
    );

    const handleMoodChange = (mood) => {
        setCurrentMood(mood);
    };

    // Function to reset journal from navigation
    const resetJournal = () => {
        setInitialContent([]);
        resetJournalID();
        setCurrentMood('happy');
    };

    // Function to capture selected blocks
    const captureSelectedBlocks = useCallback(
        (editor) => {
            const currentSelectedBlocks = editor.getSelection()?.blocks;
            const currentActiveBlock = editor.getTextCursorPosition().block;

            if (currentSelectedBlocks) {
                setSelectedBlocks(currentSelectedBlocks);
                setIsSelectionActive(true);
            } else {
                isSelectionActive && setIsSelectionActive(false);
                setSelectedBlocks([currentActiveBlock]);
            }
        },
        [selectedBlocks, isSelectionActive]
    );

    return (
        <Layout
            currentMood={currentMood}
            handleMoodChange={handleMoodChange}
            isFocusModeOn={isFocusModeOn}
            setIsFocusModeOn={setIsFocusModeOn}
            setIsPromptDisplayVisible={setIsPromptDisplayVisible}
            setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed={setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed}
            toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode}
            showFocusModeAndMoodDropdown={true}
            handleJournalUpdate={handleJournalUpdate}
            journalID={journalID}
            resetJournal={resetJournal}
        >
            <Editor
                initialContent={initialContent}
                userID={userID}
                journalID={journalID}
                handleJournalUpdate={handleJournalUpdate}
                selectedBlocks={selectedBlocks}
                setSelectedBlocks={setSelectedBlocks}
                captureSelectedBlocks={captureSelectedBlocks}
                currentMood={currentMood}
                setCurrentMood={setCurrentMood}
                isTextEditorMenuCollapsed={isTextEditorMenuCollapsed}
                setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed={setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed}
                isFocusModeOn={isFocusModeOn}
                setIsFocusModeOn={setIsFocusModeOn}
                isPromptDisplayVisible={isPromptDisplayVisible}
                setIsPromptDisplayVisible={setIsPromptDisplayVisible}
                isFocused={isFocused}
                setIsFocused={setIsFocused}
                containerRef={containerRef}
                isSelectionActive={isSelectionActive}
                setIsSelectionActive={setIsSelectionActive}
            />
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default Journal;
```

Comment: I would assume it's the first 4 lines of the useEffect, since the useEffect triggers on changes to journalID and there is a potential change being made to journalID inside the useEffect.  I would try deleting those 4 lines and going with `const [journalID, setJournalID] = useState(localStorage.getItem('journalID') || '');` to set the initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `useEffect` hook updates when the value of `journalID` updates. Here is what happens in every render.

1. Initially the value of the `journalID` state is "". The code successfully fetches the `journalID` from the local storage and calls the `setJournalID(journalIDFromLocalStorage)` function. This triggers the next `useEffect`.
2. In this render, the `fetchAndUpdateJournalStates` function will be called. In the execution flow, the line `updateJournalID(_id)` is called, effectively updating the `journalID` once again. This will trigger another render.

This is written on the assumption that unknowns like `deleteJournalEntry` does not modify the `journalID` in local storage. They will also contribute to additional renders.

#### Solution

You don't need to store `journalID` in a state. Directly pick the value from local storage and use it directly. Here is a modified code with this solution:

```
import Editor from '../components/text-editor/Editor';
import Layout from '../containers/Layout';
import { useUser } from '../contexts/UserContext';
import {
    getJournalEntryById,
    updateJournalEntry,
    createJournalEntry,
    deleteJournalEntry,
} from '../services/journalEntryService';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useMenu } from '../contexts/NavDrawerContext';

// Get the journal ID from local storage

const Journal = () => {
    const { userID, toggleDarkMode } = useUser();
    const [initialContent, setInitialContent] = useState([]);
    const [selectedBlocks, setSelectedBlocks] = useState([]);
    const [isSelectionActive, setIsSelectionActive] = useState(false);
    const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);
    const [isPromptDisplayVisible, setIsPromptDisplayVisible] = useState(false);
    const [currentMood, setCurrentMood] = useState('happy');
    const [isFocusModeOn, setIsFocusModeOn] = useState(false);
    const journalID = localStorage.getItem('journalID');

    const [isTextEditorMenuCollapsed, setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed] =
        useState(false);
    const containerRef = useRef(null);

    // Function to scroll to the bottom of the editor
    const scrollToBottom = () => {
        if (containerRef.current) {
            containerRef.current.scrollTop = containerRef.current.scrollHeight;
        }
    };

    const updateJournalID = (id) => {
        localStorage.setItem('journalID', id);
    };

    const resetJournalID = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('journalID');
    };

    // number of times the useEffect hook is called
    let effectCountRef = useRef(0);



    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(`useEffect hook called ${effectCountRef.current} times`);
        effectCountRef.current++;

        const fetchAndUpdateJournalStates = async (id) => {
            try {
                if (id?.length) {
                    const journalEntry = await getJournalEntryById(id);

                    if (journalEntry) {
                        const { content, mood, _id } = journalEntry;
                        const blocks = JSON.parse(content);
                        setInitialContent(blocks);
                        setCurrentMood(mood);
                        updateJournalID(_id);
                    }
                } else {
                    const response = await createJournalEntry(
                        initialContent,
                        currentMood
                    );
                    updateJournalID(response._id);
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(
                    'Error fetching or creating journal entry:',
                    error
                );
                resetJournalID();
            }
        };

        fetchAndUpdateJournalStates(journalID);

        return () => {
            const deleteJournalIfEmpty = async (id) => {
                try {
                    if (!id) return;

                    const response = await getJournalEntryById(id);

                    const content = JSON.parse(response.content);

                    if (content.length === 0) {
                        await deleteJournalEntry(id);
                        console.log('Journal entry deleted');
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(
                        'Error deleting journal entry if empty:',
                        error
                    );
                }
            };

            deleteJournalIfEmpty(journalID);
        };
    }, [journalID]);

    const handleJournalUpdate = useCallback(
        async (editor) => {
            // Update the content state and scroll to the bottom of the editor
            const newContent = editor.topLevelBlocks;
            captureSelectedBlocks(editor);
            scrollToBottom();

            if (newContent?.length && journalID?.length) {
                try {
                    await updateJournalEntry(journalID, 'content', newContent);
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Failed to update journal entry:', error);
                }
            }
        },
        [journalID]
    );

    const handleMoodChange = (mood) => {
        setCurrentMood(mood);
    };

    // Function to reset journal from navigation
    const resetJournal = () => {
        setInitialContent([]);
        resetJournalID();
        setCurrentMood('happy');
    };

    // Function to capture selected blocks
    const captureSelectedBlocks = useCallback(
        (editor) => {
            const currentSelectedBlocks = editor.getSelection()?.blocks;
            const currentActiveBlock = editor.getTextCursorPosition().block;

            if (currentSelectedBlocks) {
                setSelectedBlocks(currentSelectedBlocks);
                setIsSelectionActive(true);
            } else {
                isSelectionActive && setIsSelectionActive(false);
                setSelectedBlocks([currentActiveBlock]);
            }
        },
        [selectedBlocks, isSelectionActive]
    );

    return (
        <Layout
            currentMood={currentMood}
            handleMoodChange={handleMoodChange}
            isFocusModeOn={isFocusModeOn}
            setIsFocusModeOn={setIsFocusModeOn}
            setIsPromptDisplayVisible={setIsPromptDisplayVisible}
            setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed={setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed}
            toggleDarkMode={toggleDarkMode}
            showFocusModeAndMoodDropdown={true}
            handleJournalUpdate={handleJournalUpdate}
            journalID={journalID}
            resetJournal={resetJournal}
        >
            <Editor
                initialContent={initialContent}
                userID={userID}
                journalID={journalID}
                handleJournalUpdate={handleJournalUpdate}
                selectedBlocks={selectedBlocks}
                setSelectedBlocks={setSelectedBlocks}
                captureSelectedBlocks={captureSelectedBlocks}
                currentMood={currentMood}
                setCurrentMood={setCurrentMood}
                isTextEditorMenuCollapsed={isTextEditorMenuCollapsed}
                setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed={setIsTextEditorMenuCollapsed}
                isFocusModeOn={isFocusModeOn}
                setIsFocusModeOn={setIsFocusModeOn}
                isPromptDisplayVisible={isPromptDisplayVisible}
                setIsPromptDisplayVisible={setIsPromptDisplayVisible}
                isFocused={isFocused}
                setIsFocused={setIsFocused}
                containerRef={containerRef}
                isSelectionActive={isSelectionActive}
                setIsSelectionActive={setIsSelectionActive}
            />
        </Layout>
    );
};

export default Journal;
```

From React 18 and above, strict mode will trigger additional re-renders. Quoting it from [official useEffect docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect):

> When Strict Mode is on, React will run one extra development-only setup+cleanup cycle before the first real setup. This is a stress-test that ensures that your cleanup logic “mirrors” your setup logic and that it stops or undoes whatever the setup is doing. If this causes a problem, implement the cleanup function.

Though not recommended, you can remove the `<React.StrictMode>` wrapper from your root component to prevent additional renders due to `useEffect`s.